# Undefined index error : codec why its giving error nothing changes happen in database

Tags: php

Can someone explain to me where I did wrong please, if i using error_reporting its show no error but nothing happen to my database

```
<?php
 //error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

 include ("db.php");
$codec=$_POST['code'];

 if(isset($_POST['code']) && !empty($_POST['code']))
 {
     $search = mysql_query("SELECT code,active FROM users WHERE code='".$codec."'  AND active='0'") or die(mysql_error()); 
     $match  = mysql_num_rows($search);

     if($match > 0)
     {
         mysql_query("UPDATE users SET active='1' WHERE code='".$codec."' AND active='0'") or die(mysql_error());
         echo '<div class="statusmsg">Your account has been activated, you can now login</div>';
     } 
     else
     {
         // No match -> invalid url or account has already been activated.
         echo '<div class="statusmsg">The url is either invalid or you already have activated your account.</div>';
     }
 }

?>
```

Comment: shouldn't this $codec=$_POST['code'];
be inside the if condition

Comment: why this `!` in `if(!isset($_POST`

Comment: which line you are getting the error? and is this POST comes from form? if yes the npost form code also

Comment: I am getting error on line 4

Comment: Place `$codec=$_POST['code'];` inside `if(isset($_POST['code']) && !empty($_POST['code']))
 {` to read as `if(isset($_POST['code']) && !empty($_POST['code']))
 { $codec=$_POST['code']; ... rest of code` and make sure your form's element is named. I.e.: `name="code"` @shojibur

Comment: I place the code but, still it is not working , no error right noe but  showing only white page nothing happend any other suggestion

Comment: I edited my comment, I had an extra `}` in there. Reload my other comment to see it. @shojibur

Comment: I have been solved the issue , thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

you are having this problem here... change this line ...

```
if(!isset($_POST['code']) && !empty($_POST['code']))
```

to

```
if(isset($_POST['code']) && !empty($_POST['code']))
```

Comment: I change it to if(isset($_POST['code']) && !empty($_POST['code']))
but still same , any other suggestion

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: code in C:\wamp\www\Jobcafe\active.php on line 5

Answer (score 0):

Entering `12345` in the following did in fact echo `12345` so you can base yourself on this.

```
<?php

$codec=$_POST['code'];

 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(isset($_POST['code']) && !empty($_POST['code']))
    {
echo "Code :" .$codec;
    }

}

?>

<form action="" method="post">
Code: 
<input type="text" name="code">
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```